# Python and pyobdc error: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, pyodbc

I'm trying to use `pyodbc` to connect python to a MSSQL server. The development system is running Python 2.7 with Anaconda virtualenv on Mac OSX Yosemite.

Executing the following code

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER="192.168.1.106";PORT=1433;DATABASE=myDB;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;CHARSET=UTF8;TDS_Version=8.0;')
```

gives the error

```
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

Why is this causing an error?

---

I have also installed `unixodbc` and `freetds --with-unixodbc` via `homebrew`, and configured the following

**~/.odbc.ini**

```
[odbc1]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = 192.168.1.106
Port   = 1433
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

**/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf**

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
    tds version = 8.0
```

`pyodbc` package is manually installed using `python setup.py install`

**Verify**

```
$ isql odbc1 myUsername myPass
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

**Verify FreeTDS**

```
$ tsql -S sqlserver -U myUsername -P myPassword
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

There is also no problem connecting to MS SQL server using a software called Navicat

How can we troubleshoot the connection problem?

Comment: I am having the same issues, did you figure it out?

Comment: For me, `TDS_Version` 7.1 and 7.2 would connect while 7.3 and 8.0 would not.